# How to get Pubcookie username without requiring login

Tags: php, authentication

The two paragraphs after this are background information in case I'm thinking of this problem wrong. The actual question is after.

I'm creating an application for an organization that uses [Pubcookie](http://www.pubcookie.org/). In the past this has been incredibly convenient because I haven't had to implement any session authentication in order to get a user name; in PHP all I need to do is get $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] as long as the server is configured to require a valid user.

These past applications all require a login to see any content; the Apache configuration in .htaccess causes any unauthenticated users to redirect to the login server to obtain credentials. Now I'm considering an optional login system, like is used most everywhere else on the internet. I want the content to always be visible but allow the application to request a valid username.

Here's the problem: If the user is not authenticated and I am forcing authentication, pubcookie redirects them to the login server to get authenticated. If the user is authenticated, and I am forcing authentication, I can get the authentication information in $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']. If, however, the user is authenticated but I am NOT requiring authentication, I cannot get the authentication information. In order to request that information I have to require it, which locks out anonymous users.

How do I get the Pubcookie authenticated user name if it exists, without *requiring* that it exist? Asked another way, is there a way to get the user name that might sometimes return "no, there is no user name"? I've looked into PubcookieOnDemand and it seems I can set up a login script that's behind the .htaccess authentication requirement, which can set the ondemand cookie after login. However, this is not ideal as it requires the user to go to the login page whether or not the user is already authenticated. Also, there's no way to remove the ondemand cookie if the authentication expires, because the scripts don't get control until after authentication.

The only solution I've been able to find is to have a login link that stores the pubcookie authentication and hands it off to an application-managed session, but I'm feeling lazy and don't want to tackle the problem of securely tracking a user session right now. If you have some good information on doing that, though, feel free to pass me a link in a comment.

Comment: How can pubcookie know who the user is if she is not authenticated?

Comment: It doesn't; if the user is authenticated but authentication is not required I can't get the authentication. I want to be able to get the authentication in a way that allows there to be none but tells me what it is if it exists.

Comment: Please elaborate. Your sentence sounds so overall contradictory to me, that I have problems to decipher it.

Comment: I can give you an example: say the user is not authenticated. If I am forcing authentication, pubcookie redirects them to the login server to get authenticated. If the user is authenticated, and I am forcing authentication, I can get the authentication information in $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']. If, however, the user is authenticated but I am NOT requiring authentication, I cannot get the authentication information. In order to request that information I have to require it, which locks out anonymous users.

Comment: You should add the code for this part of your question: "I can get it to request on demand" to your question. This might make this more clear.

Comment: I've modified the question to clarify what I was asking, incorporating my previous comment. Thanks for helping me clarify; I was afraid I wasn't articulating the problem clearly enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like I've found my own answer in the [PubcookieNoPrompt](http://www.pubcookie.org/docs/mod_pubcookie-directives.html#PubcookieNoPrompt) Apache directive. It does...exactly what I want. It just needs to be paired with a login script that has the directive turned off, like so:

.htaccess:

```
PubcookieAppID #APPID#
PubcookieNoPrompt on
AuthType NetID
require valid-user

<Files login.php>
  PubcookieNoPrompt off
</Files>
```

The login.php file can do anything, including redirect the user based on GET data back to the page that had the login link.